# How to open atom from bash, running in windows 10?

Tags: windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I know the question has been asked before, but then closed together with a not so good answer. Time changes though, and I wonder today, if it is possible?

Comment: By bash do you mean the cmd.exe or a `.bat` file?

Comment: You are talking about the atom text editor? Be aware to edit files within WSL, you must use a tool within WSL that understands *Linux File Permissions*. If you install atom in win10 generally, and edit a file through the *lxss* folder and save, you will destroy the LInux file permissions (because apps running on windows have no concept of Linux file permissions) and the file will disappear. See [**Do not change Linux files using Windows apps and tools**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)

Comment: @Nomemorytoday Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @David C. Rankin I appreciate the warning and will have that in mind.

Comment: @James Draper Thanks for welcoming me and then giving an answer. I might have been a bit unclear in my question. By Bash I mean the
Linux shell I am using in Windows 10. From Bash I can't open the text editor Atom directly. I would like to run everything I work with from the shell. I am a novice and are trying to set up a working labenviroment for my assignments.

Answer (score 2):

To launch Atom on a specific dir use the command;

```
atom dir_of_interest
```

Answer (score 2):

First, get the file location of atom.exe in your computer. Then, add the following line at the end of your .bashrc file.

```
alias atom='/mnt/c/<FileLocation>/atom.exe'
```

Afterwards, run your files from WSL by typing

```
atom <filename>
```

Comment: This would only work from build 14951. See https://superuser.com/questions/1122188/running-win32-program-from-bash-for-windows-10

Comment: I have done the above, but instead of opening the intended file in the directory I am in, a new file with <filename> is created in directory where atom.exe is located. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: This worked for me. I had to realize however that the .bashrc file does not refresh when updated, so I had to add the alias to the current instance of the terminal as well for the current session.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install [VcXSrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv). Follow [these instructions](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/04/16/windows-susbsystem-for-linux-xfce-4/)
2. Install Atom in WSL shell following steps [here](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#debian-and-ubuntu-debapt)
3. Run `atom` in a terminal to open it

Comment: Works great! Installing with Nix does not work for some reason.

Comment: Unfortunately when trying to install packages it shows `Loading packages...` forever